# I can't browse the Internet using a windows network user

Tags: windows-xp

I work in a small company.  I have a server with Windows Server 2003 installed on it and the other PCs on the network have Windows XP SP2 .

The problem is, I have one PC that when I logon using any network user name I can see all other PCs in the network and use their shared files, but I can't browse the Internet.  When I open Internet Explorer 8 it asks me to run the Connection Diagnostic Wizard.

When I logon as a local administrator I can browse the Internet.

Please, is there anybody who has any idea how to browse the Internet using a network user?

note: all other users browse the Internet using their own network user name without any problems.

Comment: what is the output of ipconfig /all?

Comment: Can the same user reach the Internet when logging on from another machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would like to thank *Sunny* and *Igor* for their helpfull answers and to thank also  *GregD* and  *Kara Marfia* for their helpfull comments
and special thanks to *squillman* for his effort grammer correction

this is the steps i followed to solve this problem : -

1. i opened cmd.exe typed this command **ping google.com** and i got reply so i know i am online .
2. i opened **internet options** dialog from tools menu  .
3. selected connections tab in thebottom part **Local Areea Network (LAN) settings** i clicked LAN settings Button .
4. there is one choice labeled **use automatic configuration script** when i unchecked this choice the i got online .

Finally i would like to thank everybody helped me to solve this problem and a special thanks to every member in managment team of this greate wibsite

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the proxy settings in the browser for this particular user's profile? If everyone else can get online and the administrator can access the web on that same machine then the problem has to be tied to a setting/problem that is unique to that particular user's profile, either on the computer or the router that handles all the internet traffic for your office.

Answer (score 0):

Try from command prompt:

```
ping google.com
```

If this is OK (successful pings), than something on the browser settings is not. Check if the proxy server is set the same way as the other users.